# Rails multiple database connection timeout, fault tolerance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I need my rails aplication to connect multiple databases. Made a function in my model to help me with this.

```
# return true if it change the connection, false  otherwise
def self.change_connection (database_name)
  ret = false
  begin
    self.connection_handler.clear_all_connections!()
    self.establish_connection :"#{database_name}"
    @@db_conf_name = database_name
    ret = true
  rescue
    self.connection_handler.clear_all_connections!() 
    self.establish_connection  :"#{@@db_conf_name}" unless @@db_conf_name.empty?
  end
  ret
end
```

This work great if all the databases are up and running, but when the app changes to a database that isn't online, this method doesn't gives any exception and the app gets stuck in the first interaction with the database until the webserver timeout(60 secs).

I try this change, but it doesn't work either:

```
Timeout::timeout(2){
  self.connection_handler.clear_all_connections!()
  self.establish_connection :"#{database_name}"
  #dummy query force to establish the connection
  connection.execute("SELECT 1 from broadcasts")
}
```

this timeout is never triggered.

Is there a way to configure a timeout or a way to check if the database is online and timeout in 2 or 3 seconds?